# Who is Fu in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

So apparently in the new Dragon Ball Heroes anime an evil saiyan is going to be resurrected by a character named Fu. Who is Fu in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fu is a character who made his debut in Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2. He is a mutation of the 2 main Antagonists of the game, *Mira and Towa*. He comes from the *Demon Realm* and was considered to be *Dabura's successor*, (Note: Dabura is the same Demon King from Dragon Ball Z whose sister happens to be Towa).

Despite being an antagonist and having a rather evil appearance, you couldn't necessarily call him evil. He is a very powerful being and inherited his power from *Mira* and at the same time, he also inherited *Towa's*  intelligence, hence making him very interested in science.

He was originally created in Dragon Ball Online and made an appearance in the guidebook, however, his first debut is in Xenoverse 2 in the latest DLC. You can find out more about the character by playing Fu's arc in the game.